# Is Wolverine sterile?

Tags: marvel, wolverine, biology

Pretty much just that...it seems like there would be a lot of little (and not so little) Wolverines running around by now if not. Surely this is addressed somewhere in the comics.

Comment: Wolverine has traditionally been portrayed as falling in love with someone and then being almost ridiculously faithful even if the feelings are not reciprocated (e.g. Jean Grey). He's never really been shown to be the type to sleep around.

Comment: @phantom42: That varies HUGELY by writer.  Yes, he's been seen to have a few long(ish) relationships, but those have invariably caused him pain - Yuriko, Jean, the lady in Canada who saved him...his serial monogamy causes almost as much death as his claws.  So he periodically tries to do the 'uncaring one-night-stand' thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One comic story arc featuring Wolverine had him and his loved ones as the target of a large organization, which sought to destroy him by destroying that which he loved.

He (predictably) slaughtered them all, destroying the organization root and branch.  He had the most trouble with their hit squad, a group known as the Mongrels.

It was then revealed to him that this was part of the overall plan - the mastermind behind it knew he'd emerge victorious...and had recruited the Mongrels entirely from his illegitimate offspring.

If he's had enough accidental children to build a superhuman hit squad out of them, it's safe to say he isn't sterile.

Answer (score 7):

No he is not sterile, in the original comics he does have some children namely:
Jimmy Hudson (son in the Ultimate Marvel universe),
Erista Logan,
Daken Akihiro.

Answer (score 4):

Daken, his son, had an entire series dedicated to him (Dark Wolverine) in addition to being the focus of the main Wolverine book for quite some time. So, in addition to the storyline that Jeff mentions, there's some pretty obvious proof that he isn't sterile.